# Prove that $S_{n}/n$ converges to $X$ almost surely where $S_{n} = X_{1} + X_{2} + X_{3} + \ldots + X_{n}$ and $n\geq 1$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the random variables $X$, $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $\ldots$ such that $X_{n}\to X$ almost surely.

Prove that $S_{n}/n$ converges to $X$ almost surely where $S_{n} = X_{1} + X_{2} + X_{3} + \ldots + X_{n}$ and $n\geq 1$

This is what I have tried.

To begin with, let us note the following relation holds:
\begin{align*}
\{\omega\in\Omega : X_{n}(\omega) \to X(\omega)\} \subseteq \left\{\omega\in\Omega : \frac{X_{1}(\omega) + X_{2}(\omega) + \ldots + X_{n}(\omega)}{n} \to X(\omega)\right\}
\end{align*}

Since the first event occurs with probability one, so it does the second due to the monotonicity of the probability measure.

Can someone criticize my solution?

Comment: Your proof  is correct.

Comment: When you "note" that that relation holds it looks to me like you're proving something by simply noting it's true - that relation is exactly what needs to be proved.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Is this related to the Cesàro's sum?